# Implementation options of summing, averaging, concatenating, etc items in an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delegates, anonymous-methods

I'm looking for the shortest code to create methods to perform common operations on items in an IEnumerable.

For example:

```
public interface IPupil
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

1. Summing a property - e.g. IPupil.Age in IEnumerable<IPupil>
2. Averaging a property - e.g. IPupil.Age in IEnumerable<IPupil>
3. Building a CSV string - e.g. IPupil.Name in IEnumerable<IPupil>

I'm interested in the various approaches to solve these examples: foreach (long hand), delegates, LINQ, anonymous methods, etc...

Sorry for the poor wording, I'm having trouble describing exactly what I'm after!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Summing and averaging: easy with LINQ:

```
var sum = pupils.Sum(pupil => pupil.Age);
var average = pupils.Average(pupil => pupil.Age);
```

Building a CSV string - there are various options here, including writing your own extension methods. This will work though:

```
var csv = string.Join(",", pupils.Select(pupil => pupil.Name).ToArray());
```

Note that it's tricky to compute *multiple* things (e.g. average *and* sum) in one pass over the data with normal LINQ. If you're interested in that, have a look at the [Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx) project which Marc Gravell and I have written. It's a pretty specialized requirement though.

Comment: Thanks Jon. LINQ looks like everything I need!

Comment: LINQ is indeed fabulous beyond all measure :)